# Please help me to solve this error I'm unable to update nodejs version

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, nodejs

dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_15.14.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please post the exact command that your run.

Comment: ... and the whole error message. This is just saying that `dpkg` failed due to an error ... The actual error is before that.